# Varnish VCL check if cookie does not exist

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I need to check for a `designexception` if a cookie does not exist.

I only know how to check if a cookie exists.

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "cookiename") {}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok I think I found it out. Is like in other languages.

if (!req.http.Cookie ~ "cookiename") {}